# Getting 502 (Proxy Error) When Browsing Node.js Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, proxy

I have configured Node.js server with the Apache server via proxy, proxy_http modes and it was working fine. But now when I start my Node.js server, I get the running notification message on ssh console which is: **"ok, server is running"**, but when I access the Node.js server via browser `http://example.com/node/`, I get **502 Error (Proxy Error)** - Before I was getting 200 status!

I don't know why now I am unable to get 200 status! I haven't changed anything for the Node.js server file. The owner is root:root. I rebooted the Ubuntu 12.04 server and it was working after the reboot.

The modules **proxy** and **proxy_http** are enabled.

I got the below errors from Apache log:

```
(20014)Internal error: proxy: error reading status line from remote server localhost:9000

proxy: Error reading from remote server returned by /node
```

Below is the sites-available `/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com` configuration to enable proxy

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    .
    .
    ProxyPass /n  http://localhost:9000/
    ProxyPassReverse /n  http://localhost:9000/
    .
    .
</VirtualHost>
```

The Node.js server code:

```
var http=require('http');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var util = require('util');
var url = require('url');

var server=http.createServer(function(req,res){
     //res.end('Connected');
});


server.on('listening',function(){
    console.log('ok, server is running');
});

server.listen(9000);
```

I would greatly appreciate your inputs as I have tried a lot with no luck :(

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I comment the response at server, then it will not work and will get **Error 502**. It should be:

```
var server=http.createServer(function(req,res){
    res.end('Connected');
});
```